# iis url-rewrite for no script name

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

We would like to redirect IIS traffic with URL [www.site1.com](http://www.site1.com) to [www.site2.com](http://www.site2.com).  We do not want to redirect traffic for url's with either folder names and or script names.  In other words we do NOT want to redirect a URL like [www.site1.com/someFolder](http://www.site1.com/someFolder) or [www.site1.com/somePage.php](http://www.site1.com/somePage.php), but if the URL is "plain" [www.site1.com](http://www.site1.com) we want to redirect to  [www.site2.com](http://www.site2.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below rule:

```
<rule name="Redirect 1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost:820/" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

you can set redirect URL based on your requirement